# MVVM - Wrapping Class For ViewModel

Tags: c#, mvvm, wpf

I am using a networking library I created which contains a `Client` class. I have a GUI which will display all these clients in a `ListView` with columns, such as one containing their online status. The online status property is only for the UI, so it is not present in the class in the networking library.

What I am currently doing is creating a `ClientModel` class which contains a property for the `Client`, and additionally contains an `isOnline` property. I then add these 'ClientModel's to an `ObservableCollection` in my ViewModel, which is bound to the `ListView` `ItemsSource` in the `XAML`.

My question is this: When I have a class that I want to add properties which will be bound to the UI, is it right to making a "model wrapper" and doing what I am doing? Also, I am a bit confused if this would be considered a model or viewmodel (i.e, would it be `ClientViewModel` or `ClientModel`?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is this: When I have a class that I want to add properties which will be bound to the UI, is it right to making a "model wrapper" and doing what I am doing?

Yes, that is exactly what a ViewModel should be: a wrapper for the Model to adapt it to the needs of a View.